# How does Discriminant of splitting field of irreducible polynomial $f$ related to discriminant of $f $ ??

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

Can we  express  Discriminant of splitting field of polynomial $f$  in terms of the discriminant of $f .$

Comment: What is your definition for the discriminant of the splitting field?